# How can I declare an object globally and then use it in a method

Tags: global, declaration

I declared a method UISearchBar *searrchBar Globally and also synthesized it.

I've created a table view in which under cell.textLabel.text I would like to use this searrchBar, how can I do it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
int abc=0;

void method(){
    abc++;//do what ever you want
}
```